Getting PDF file from s3
So im uploading this pdf file to s3 which is happening fine, but second step is to get that pdf from s3 so I can download it whenever I can, but when I get to the download step im getting a file with 0 bytes, I checked on s3 and the file is downloading correctly through there.... this is my code to get the file from s3, its getting inside the if condition too, also checked the buffer size coming from s3 and its not empty:
const s3 = new AWS.S3({
                    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ID,
                    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET
                });

                const params = {
                    Bucket: `${process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME}/receipts`,
                    Key: `${transactionId}.pdf`
                };

                s3.getObject(params, async (err, data) => {
                    if (err) {
                        rollbar.error(err);
                        new Logger().error(err);
                        return RouteResponse.error('Error retrieving file from S3', res);
                    }

                
                    if (data.Body && Buffer.isBuffer(data.Body)) {
                        return new HtmlPdf().renderBuffer(res, data.Body);
                    }
                    return RouteResponse.error('File data is not valid', res);
                });
            } else {
                return RouteResponse.error('File not found or transaction does not exist', res);
            }

and this is my renderBuffer:
/**
     * renderBuffer
     *
     * @param { Response<unknown, Record<string, unknown>> }_res - Response
     * @param { Buffer } buffer - Buffer do arquivo
     */
    public async renderBuffer(_res: Response<unknown, Record<string, unknown>>, buffer: Buffer): Promise<void> {
        const readStream = new stream.PassThrough();
        readStream.end(buffer);
        _res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/pdf');
        _res.setHeader('Content-disposition', `attachment; filename=report.pdf`);
        readStream.pipe(_res);
    }
    ```


The s3.getObject() call is asynchronous. Use async/await. And consider moving to v3 of the SDK.

Almost all of the AWS SDK API calls are asynchronous and return promises. If you handle the responses in a callback, as follows, then your call to get_object() completes before the s3.getObject callback happens and your `get_object() function actually returns undefined.
function get_object(Bucket, Key)
{
    s3.getObject({ Bucket, Key }, async (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error("GetObject failed, err=", err);
        } else {
            // this is the return value of the callback function and is
            // NOT the return value of the get_object() call
            return data.Body.toString('utf-8');
        }
    });
    // implicit return undefined here
}

// data will (incorrectly) always be undefined
const data = get_object("somebucket", "somekey");

You can modify your code to use async/await, for example:
async function get_object(Bucket, Key)
{
    const data = await s3.getObject({ Bucket, Key });
    return data.Body.toString('utf-8');
}

// data will (correctly) be the S3 object's body content
const data = await get_object("somebucket", "somekey");

Also, be aware that the AWS JavaScript SDK v2 has been updated and you should consider using v3 going forward.
